# Android Jelly Bean resume after moveTaskToBack(true)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-4.1-jelly-bean

i have some problem with android Jelly Bean. 
I want to load webview in background activity, and when webivew site is complete loaded, i want to show activity.
For send activity in background i use `Activity.moveTaskToBack(true);`, and to resume it `startActivity` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. It's worked perfect on all versions expect Jelly Bean :(. On Jelly Bean Activity.onResume executed but activity not showed.

Example code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(webView);
        setContentView(layout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        moveTaskToBack(true);

        Toast.makeText(this, "SEND ACTIVITY TO BACK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "TRY RESUME ACTIVITY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, 10000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        Toast.makeText(this, "ON NEW INTENT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Toast.makeText(this, "ON RESUME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```